# Webpack Node.js on Heroku Deployment Error

Tags: node.js, git, postgresql, heroku, webpack

I built an application with **React/Node.js/PostgreSQL** Webpack and now attempting to deploy on heroku.

Everything works perfectly on my localhost, but it doesn't serve on Heroku. [error message image on Heroku](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LBEGR.png) -

I've tried multiple buildpacks to make it happen, but it still gives me the same result, and I cannot figure out the problem as my logs don't seem to have any issues.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the link to my repo https://github.com/strongharris/Edu-it

**To Run it:** 
npm install ->
npm run build ->
npm start

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is with your code. I tried to deploy a copy of your project to Heroku, and it's giving me an error because `config.connection` does not exist when you use it in a conditional.

Here's the error:

[image: Error Logs]

(These logs were retrieved by me deploying the Heroku app, then running `heroku logs` to view the log output.)

As you can see, the error is here: https://github.com/strongharris/Edu-it/blob/master/server/database/database_config.js#L9

You'll need to re-write this code so it runs properly without that variable.